# How to assign a value to a specific variable from the user input

Tags: variables, user-input, assign

How can I assign a value to a specific variable when the console is asking for user input? I would like to have something where I can type in the console 
`time_h = 5`
and assign the value 5 to the existing variable `time_h` directly from the console. I don't want to just simply write something like 
`time_h = input()` 
and type a number when the console pops up.

Comment: Consider using `sys` module that lets you handle command-line arguments with `sys.argv`.

Comment: @balkon16 can you please give me an example, I'm really new to writing code and Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've indicated in the comment, you can use `sys` module in order to handle command-line arguments that are supplied with the script call. Let's consider the following script that is called `example_sys.py`:

```
import sys

print("The name of the script that you have called is {}".format(sys.argv[0]))
time_h = int(sys.argv[1])
print("The value of the time_h variable is {}".format(time_h))
```

Assuming that you've `cd`ed with your console into the directory that contains the `example_script.py` you can call it with a command-line argument that is separeted with a space:

```
python example_sys.py 5
```

Depending on the Python version that is assigned to `python` command you might need to use `python3` instead of `python`.